# Boost Graph Library astar_search for implicit graphs

Tags: c++, boost, graph, a-star, boost-graph

I would like to apply the `astar_search()` algorithm to an implicit graph that generates over time. The initialization of a new vertex in the graph is thereby quite involved and requires an external lookup in another data structure.

I have looked into quite a few examples that use `astar_search()`, but could not find a lot with implicit graphs. From all the examples that use implicit graphs [[1]](http://cs.krisbeevers.com/research/astar_bgl04.pdf) looks the most promising. The problem with the proposed solution is, that `astar_search()` takes a const graph reference (`const VertexListGraph &g`) as a parameter in boost 1.66, thus prohibiting the modification and addition of new vertices and edges to the graph in the `examine_vertex` visitor.

Another proposed solution I saw was [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547097/boost-implicit-graph-and-astar-search-no-init). Although I'm not quite sure that I fully understand every bit of the code, I think the `astar_search_no_init()` function does not fit my problem either, since I already start with a partially computed graph and a simple default construction of a new vertex is problematic, due to the vertex creation with the external lookup described above.

I guess the easiest, yet not working, solution to my problem would be an `examine_vertex` visitor that is able to modify the graph. 
Do you guys have any idea what I could do instead or know a workaround solution?

[[1]](http://cs.krisbeevers.com/research/astar_bgl04.pdf) A* Graph Search Within the BGL Framework (p.12-19)

[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547097/boost-implicit-graph-and-astar-search-no-init) Stack Overflow Question: boost implicit graph and astar_search_no_init